# Indenting a c file adds spaces before function's type?

Tags: indentation, filetype-c

Open a `c` file and then type:

```
int
main
```

and then hit:

<kbd>gg=G</kbd>

It becomes

```
    int
main
```

Is this an intended behavior? Is there a way to change this? I prefer it to be retained as is because most projects have it like that.

Here are some settings that I have:

```
set fr          # c
set cindent     # cindent
set ai          # autoindent
set si          # smartindent
set indentexpr  #
```

Comment: Well, that command reformats the entire file. How it does indentation depends on your configuration. What does `:set ai? si? cidnent? indentexpr? ft?` return? And if you don't have syntatically correct C code then the formatting might not look so great (garbage-in, garbage-out). Is there some code surrounding what you've shown?

Comment: suggest, as a reasonable suggestion: place the return type (which is part of the function signature) on the same line as the rest of the function signature

Comment: @BLayer, updated that. It is syntactically valid code. I am able to reproduce even with `int` and `main` though.

Comment: @user3629249, most projects like Linux and FreeBSD uses this convention. So I was trying to use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a C file and have a look at `cinoptions`

```
set cinoptions?
```

Most likely this is empty. Now add `t0`.

```
set cinoptions+=t0
```

Reformat your C code, and the type should not be indented anymore.

See `:help 'cinoptions'` and `:help cinoptions-values`. There you find that indenting the type by one `'shiftwidth'` is the default (when on line for it own).

If `cinoptions` is not empty and already contains a entry `tN` (`N` is a number),
you have to remove it first:

```
set cinoptions-=tN    "replace N with actual number
```